# Добавление листов excel

Tags: c#, excel

Пытаюсь разобраться в работе с ексель посредством c#, не могу понять как добавить лист в существующую книгу. Листы находятся в разных файлах, мне нужно их засунуть в одну книгу. Пока делаю так, но это слишком затратно и топорно:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main ( string[] args )
    {
        var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var excelApp = new Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open( $"{dir}\\MAN.xls" );
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем делать видимым Excel??? делайте что хотите при Visible=false  и только потом показывайте

Comment: @Bald56rus, меня тревожит не то что происходит на экране, а как раз сама концепция открытия книги на каждый новый лист.

Comment: в свое время пробовал работать с excel, первое что я узнал что операции по наполнению книги делать надо в visible=false это работает быстрее.не совсем понял что вы хотите сделать?из разных книг получить определенные листы и вставить их в одну книгу?

Comment: Добавьте using, не понятно, что вы используете

Comment: @Bald56rus, технически видимо так, я думал что можно открыть лист сразу в существующую книгу, а не создавать новую. Знаете, можно создать просто лист excel или это предполагает что априори он находится в отдельной книге?

Comment: в открытую книгу добавить пустой лист возможно, тут вопрос чем Вы хотите его наполнять?другим листом из другого документа? алгоритм вырисовывается следующий: пробегаетесь по интересующим файлам, получаете из них необходимую информацию формируете результат

Comment: @Bald56rus, я понимаю что можно наполнить лист информацией другого листа, мне было как раз интересно есть ли обходной путь этого алгоритма, что бы сразу открыть в существующую книгу файл с листом/листами. Видимо что нет такого.

Comment: Вероятно вам может подойти этот код:
[Копирование листа Excel из одной книги в другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740831/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-excel-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E)

Answer (score 1):

Использовать Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel желательно только в том случае, если нужно создавать экземпляр приложения Excel и работать с ним в интерективном режиме.

С файлами в формате Excel надежнее работать через библиотеки [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) или [OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), которые не требуют установки самого приложения Microsoft Excel. Для работы на сервере установка клиентских приложений нежелатено.

NPOI - это порт java библиотеки по работе с xls файлами (до Excel 2007).

OpenXML - это библиотека для работы с новым форматом xslx (Excel 2007 и выше)

Обе библиотеки содержат функционал по работе и с другими типами документов Microsoft Office.